# Help Shortening a Regular Expression with repeated subpatterns

Tags: regex

I have generated the following regular expression in a project I am working on, and it works fine, but out of professional curiosity I was wondering If it can be "compressed/shortened":

```
  /[(]PRD[)].+;.+;.*;.+;.+;.*;.*;.*;/
```

Regexes have always seemed like voodoo to me...

Comment: What is the exact pattern you are looking for?  e.g. what does the match result set look like?

Comment: Yeah, if the problem is "match exactly what this regex matches" then it's hard to compress it much.  John's was pretty good at a more elegant approach.  Some samples of match content would help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, the single-character blocks can just go away:

```
/\(PRD\).+;.+;.*;.+;.+;.*;.*;.*;/
```

Next, you can group the related items together:

```
/\(PRD\)(.+;){2}.*;(.+;){2}(.*;){3}/
```

This actually makes it textually longer, though.

Comment: And since the '.' should probably be '[^;]' each time, the rewrite then becomes a whole lot shorter - like 15 characters shorter than the amended original.

Comment: There could also be an argument that the '(...)' sequences should be '(?:...)' (non-capturing groupings) since the original did not contain any captures.  There's another argument that the original probably wants the groupings, but then there'd be a question of whether it is better to split on ';'.

Answer (score 3):

```
/\(PRD\)(.+;.+;.*;){2}(.*;){2}/
```

is shorter than

```
/\(PRD\)((.+;){2}.*;){2}(.*;){2}/
```

but arguably less awesome. Both are successfully shorter than

```
/[(]PRD[)].+;.+;.*;.+;.+;.*;.*;.*;/
```

though (if only because of the character class change).

Or you could even go with

```
/\(PRD\)(.+;.+;.*;){2}.*;.*;/
```

which *may* be the shortest you can get with the same rules.

Comment: +1 shortest with the same rules - now, if you bend the rules a bit ... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
/\(PRD\).+;.+;.*;.+;.+;(.*;){3}/
```

I don't think you will gain much and arrive at the same exact rules. If you didn't care to make all the text between the ";" optional, then you could:

```
/\(PRD\)(.*;){8}/
```